# How to use order in collection method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my code i am not able to sort the name by first_name

```
 <%= f.collection_select :donation_id, @donation_array,
      :id,  :dropdown_display,:order => ("first_name DESC"),
      :prompt => "Select Donation Detail", :include_blank => true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order it like this, it is done when you are pulling donation_array like this

```
@donation_array = Donation.order('first_name DESC').all
```

and create your collection like this

```
<%= f.collection_select :donation_id, @donation_array,
      :id,  :dropdown_display,
      :prompt => "Select Donation Detail", :include_blank => true %>
```